# DBT and Databricks

Tags: task, databricks, dbt

When trying to get DBT transformations to happen in Databricks I get this error;

```
Task DBT_Normalization failed with message: Failed to archive dbt artifacts. This caused all downstream tasks to get skipped
```

I tried checking the connection between DBT and Databricks, I changed the run statement in databricks, made a new profiles.yml file for the schema, changed the source, removed the `dbt seeds`, and im still getting the same error.

Comment: Show how the task is configured and what your directory layout

Answer (score -1):

The error message you provided indicates that the task `"DBT_Normalization"` failed, and as a result, all downstream tasks are being skipped.

- This means that there was a problem during the execution of the DBT transformation, and the subsequent tasks that depend on it cannot be executed.

Note that this error could be caused by:

- A problem with the DBT configuration.
- A problem with the Databricks cluster.
- A problem with the underlying database.

**Here are some things you can check to troubleshoot this error:**

- **Check the DBT configuration.** Make sure that the paths to the artifacts are correct. You can do this by checking the target directory in your DBT project. If the directory does not exist, or if the artifacts are not in the correct location, you will need to update the configuration.
- **Check the Databricks cluster.** Make sure that the cluster has enough resources to run DBT. You can check this by looking at the cluster's CPU and memory usage. If the cluster is not running enough resources, you may need to increase the cluster size.
- **Check the underlying database.** Make sure that the database is accessible and that the user account that DBT is using has the necessary permissions. You can check this by trying to connect to the database from another client. If you are unable to connect, you will need to troubleshoot the database connection.

If you have checked all of these things and you are still getting the error, you can try the following:

- Delete the target directory and run DBT again. This will force DBT to re-archive the artifacts.
- Use the `dbt debug` command to get more information about the error. This will show you the exact error message and the stack trace. This information can be helpful in troubleshooting the error.

Refer here: https://docs.databricks.com/partners/prep/dbt.html

**Let me know if you have been able to troubleshoot the error.**

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT